# How to add td after a td

Tags: html

I have a td and I want to add a new one, but my new td is shown as text on my page, what am I missing
my code :

```
        var firstTd = parent.document.getElementById("currentTd");           
        firstTd.after('<td><span>teste</span></td>');
```

Comment: You might have thought you're using the [jQuery `.after()`](https://api.jquery.com/after/), but you're actually using the native [`.after()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/after).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/after):

> The Element.after() method inserts a set of Node or string objects in the children list of the Element's parent, just after the Element. **String objects are inserted as equivalent Text nodes**.

So pass an element instead.

```
const firstTd = parent.document.getElementById("currentTd");           
const secondTd = document.createElement('td');
const span = document.createElement('span');
span.textContent = "teste";
secondTd.appendChild(span);
firstTd.after(secondTd);
```

or consider [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

Comment: `firstTd` does not seem a jQuery object in the first place, which I assume OP expects. https://api.jquery.com/after/

Comment: @connexo — I think you assume wrong. My answer certainly doesn't assume that.

Comment: If I had to guess, OP thought they'd be using jQuery's `.after()`, which explicitly shows examples like `$(".inner").after("<p>Test</p>")`, and got caught by a same-name DOM method that does not support passing an HTML string. Tagging their question [tag:jquery] (which you removed in an edit) supports this assumption.